# probability sum of three dice $\geq 13$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

What is the probability that the sum of three thrown fair dice is $\geq13$?

I did the brute force method and wrote down all tupels. But I am not sure if it is right:

I got $\frac{53}{216}$.

Is it correct?

Maybe there is a more elegant way to get the probability but I don't see it.

Comment: Have you heard of generating functions?

Comment: @UriToti, no I haven't

Comment: I recommend you to take a look. Maybe it does not help you with computation, but it offers a simpler description. In The Art of Probability, Hamming, there is a nice section about generating functions (the case of the sum of dice appears).

Comment: $\frac{53}{216}$ is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as the combinations that $4$ dice sum to $19.$  This is only because there are 6 values in the  $13-18$ range for three dice.   So, each of these possibilities matches with a potential outcome on a theoretical 4th die.

${18\choose 3} - {4\choose 1}{12\choose 3} + {4\choose 2}{6\choose 3}$

Or, even nicer - the combinations of 4 dice that sum to 19 is the same as the combinations of 4 dice that sum to 9.

${8\choose 3} = 56$

Answer (score 0):

All possible sums are $3,4,5,...,18$

By symmetry, the cases for $18$ is same as $3$, $17$ is same as $4$, and so on, so we need to consider only $3$ to $10$.

As a tool, we know the number of solution to $a_1+a_2+a_3=n$ where $a_i$s are all positive integer is ${n-1 \choose 2}$ as we can imagine there are $n$ balls and we put $2$ sticks in between the balls in order to separate them into three separate groups.

Now back to the sums:

$S=3,18: {2\choose 2}=1$

$S=4,17: {3\choose 2}=3$

$S=5,16: {4\choose 2}=6$

$S=6,15: {5\choose 2}=10$

$S=7,14: {6\choose 2}=15$

$S=8,13: {7\choose 2}=21$. Note since $a_1+a_2+a_3=8$ can have no positive solution where $a_i>6$, so we can just use the formula up to this point.

$S=9,12: {8\choose 2}-{3\choose 1}{1\choose 1}=25$. Note here we need to minus the number of solution where we fix one of $a_i$ to be $7$, and for example when $a_3=7$ the number of solutions for $a_1+a_2=9-7$.

$S=10,11: {9\choose 2}-{3\choose 1}{2\choose 1}-{3\choose 1}{1\choose 1}=27$.

Now we count the possibiliy of $S$ at least $13$:

$${1+3+6+10+15+21\over 216}={56\over 216}$$

Comment: Notice that $56$ is also ${8\choose 3}$, but if we ask for sum at least $12$ then the number becomes $81$ which is not a counting number so I think there is no solution that involves only a single case without breaking into multiple cases.